# Update columns based on condition PL/SQL setting them as NULL

Tags: if-statement, plsql, null, sql-update, case

I wanted to update columns based on condition: There is this table with columns A, B, C, D, E.

[image: Table]

These columns with values are to be updated with null. I **do not want to touch the columns without any values**.

...

```
UPDATE
    Table
SET 
  A = CASE WHEN A!=NULL THEN A=NULL
  B= CASE WHEN B!=NULL THEN B=NULL 
  C= CASE WHEN C!=NULL THEN C='U'
  D= CASE WHEN D!=NULL THEN D=NULL ELSE END,
WHERE
    where condition;
```

...

PS:: The column values are not same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query was almost close.Below one should work,

```
  update test_Data 
     set  A = CASE WHEN A is not NULL THEN NULL END,
       B = CASE WHEN B is not NULL THEN NULL END ,
       C = CASE WHEN C is not  NULL THEN NULL END,
       D = CASE WHEN D is not   NULL THEN NULL END,
       E = CASE WHEN E = 'abc' THEN 'QWE' ELSE E END
     where (A is not NULL or B is not NULL or C is not NULL or D is not null or E is not null)
```

**UPDATE:**

If any of the column has NOT NULL Constraint, then column has to be altered to take NULL.

```
alter table test_Data modify E null;
```

for demo with example refer DB fiddle link - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7f8bfc2f5edda71a9eb5af5ccb2065de

Comment: The thing you need to get firmly in your mind: *NULL IS NULL*. It basically introduces 3-way logic where logical results can be True, False, or Null. So the result of A=Null returns Null so does A!=Null, and (perhaps what appears stranger) the result of Null=Null is not true/false it is Null.  Likewise, Null !=Null is also Null. Get that idea firmly planted Null is Null. (There are some exceptions -of course- but they are the the unusual case). And you will have no trouble like here.

Comment: @VN'Corner Thanks for the update. But there is another column say E which can accept user-defined values say 'X', 'Y' and 'Z'. So when I go and use this query I get an error saying cannot update 'E' to NULL. Please suggest how to handle this part.

Comment: Seems like column E has NOT NULL constraint, so by the column definition itself you cannot update the column to NULL in any database for that matter. Table has to be altered to modify column E to take NULL. Refer updated dbfiddle link in the answer.

Comment: VN'sCorner yes, I do not want to make it null. I want it to b some value say 'QWE'. So if it has any value say 'ABC' it should be changed to 'QWE'. But it should not make it as null

Comment: modified the query, it is as simple as modifying the case expression.

Comment: I modify it as ... E= CASE WHEN E!='X' THEN 'X' END... But as I said it is through an error saying cannot update E to null.

Comment: Add ELSE to the CASE to update back to E when condition not met. The answer has been updated.